# Libgdx : how to shuffle small part of a big array

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, game-development

I'm trying to make a matching game. I have taken 2 arrays (size 26 both) in 1st array i have stored Alphabets from A-Z and in
2nd array i have stored images of things that start with A-Z alphabets respectively . I draw the 5-5 images of both array (not all of them at once) parallel to each other. but before that i shuffled the both arrays.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxDXT.png) in the Fisrt shuffle it goes perfectly, but when i shuffle the both array on 2nd time for further 5-5 array, then it shows some previous images too.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfklV.png) can anyone help me find a bug?

```
Shuffle(alphabets, previousIndex +5,pictures,previousIndex + 5);
```

public void  Shuffle(Image[] firstCol, int sizeFirst, Image[] secondCol, int sizeSecond){

```
        for (int i = sizeFirst-1 ; i >previousIndex; i--) {

            int j = rand.nextInt(i+1);
            Image temp = firstCol[i];
            firstCol[i] = firstCol[j];
            firstCol[j] = temp;
            System.out.println("i="+i+" j="+j);
        }

        for (int i = sizeSecond -1; i >previousIndex; i--) {
            int j = rand.nextInt(i+1);
            Image temp = secondCol[i];
            secondCol[i] = secondCol[j];
            secondCol[j] = temp;
        }
        previousIndex += 5;

    ShowAlphabets(firstCol,secondCol);

}
```

Comment: `nextInt(bound)` ranges from [0 .. bound) so when invoked on the second 5x5 `int j = rand.nextInt(i+1)` will range from [0..10) (i=9 on first iteration).  Is that really what you want?  Seems like on the 2nd call to `Shuffle` you'd want images randomly selected from [5..10).

Comment: yes.... exactly

Comment: Something like int j = rand.nextInt(5) + previousIndex would yield ranges such as [0,5) on the first invocation of Shuffle and [5,10) on the next invocation, etc.

Comment: No.. its not working.........